# Как быстро и просто сделать frontend сайта новичку

Tags: c#, asp.net, frontend, веб-сайт

Я хочу сделать учебный пет-проект - интернет магазин книг. Делаю упор в backend. В frontend'е не разбираюсь от слова совсем, поэтому вряд-ли смогу сделать что-то визуально красивое, а если этот проект пойдет в портфолио, то хотелось бы, чтобы и визуал не страдал. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь способ быстро склепать приятный визуал (возможно есть какой-нибудь способ собрать простой макет из шаблонов, блоков и т.д.), чтобы потом подвязать его к API бэкенда.

Если это имеет значение, backend я собираюсь писать на C# под платформу asp.net

Comment: Открываете гугл, пишете `Free HTML Templates`, находите любой интересующий вас, закидываете в проект файлы, открываете HTML, копируете текст в нужные файлы проекта, возвращаете теги разметки от ASP обратно. Готово. Что-то более простого, думаю вряд-ли найдете.

Comment: Ну берите готовые html, css файлы (темплейт), а дальше через какой-нибудь FetchJs привязываете вашу апишку. Если хотите что-то красивое, и функциональное, то SPA через ReactJs, это не слишком сложно, html, css можно освоить на базовом уровне достаточно быстро, если только у новичка могут быть проблемы с адаптивной версткой.